# Force sequential evaluation for non thread-safe Consumer in Java

Tags: java, thread-safety, java-stream

With the Java8 stream API, is it somehow possible to force a Stream to be processed sequentially from a consumer?

When i have a `java.util.function.Consumer` of which I know it's not threadsafe I would like to force the Streams API to processes it sequentially, since running parallel would 'always' result in buggy behavior.

This snippet illustrates my problem:

```
static class NonThreadsafeConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {

    @Override
    public void accept(T arg0) {
        //Do non-threadsafe stuff here
    }
}

public void doIt(Stream<String> stream) {
    //Unknown behaviour
    stream.forEach(new NonThreadsafeConsumer<>());
    // Bug for sure
    stream.parallel().forEach(new NonThreadsafeConsumer<>());
    // Correct
    stream.sequential().forEach(new NonThreadsafeConsumer<>());
}
```

The problem i have with this a that I as the author of the `NonThreadsafeConsumer` dont want to trust the implementor of the `doIt()` method to always know and remember to put in a `.sequential()` call

(Note making the consumer threadsafe is not the point of my question, I just like to know if this CAN be done)

Comment: If `NonThreadsafeConsumer` class is the only place you want to change, then I suppose no

Comment: The best you could do here is to mention that it is not thread safe in its javadoc

Comment: I can't tell if you're looking for [`Stream#forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) or not.

Comment: @JacobG. no i like to see this as a problem for the author of the Consumer wanting to not let the user of this consumer make a (expected) mistake

Comment: You could use locks in `accept` method

Comment: Are you OK with throwing a `RuntimeException` if the consumer detects it's being consumed concurrently?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Can you explain how we can achieve that?

Comment: @user7 you could use an `AtomicBoolean` as an attribute of the consumer, initially set to `false`. When a thread enters to the `accept` method, check-and-sets it to `true`, but only allows the thread to proceed if the flag was `false`, otherwise throw an exception. At the end, in a `finally` block, the flag is set to `false` again. Something like that...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner ok. I get it. If we need to allow sequential access instead of throwing an exception, will using a static `Object` lock (synchronized block on static Object) in the consumer work?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that would not be cheaper than making the `accept` method `synchronized`, especially if we assume that correctly using code is always calling the method from the same thread (say “biased locking” or even “lock elimination”)…

Comment: @user7 Just making the method `synchronized` would do it.

Comment: @Holger Absolutely, it would be a waste of resources when the consumer is used sequentially, only to detect a wrong usage. I totally agree with you, in fact, I haven't written an answer with this `AtomicBoolean` flag stuff because I totally subscribe to what you've explained in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of enforcing a single-threaded use of your `Consumer`, at least not without an overhead in the same order of magnitude than just making the `Consumer` thread safe.

But it is not the responsibility of the `Consumer` to enforce a single-threaded usage. In Java, not being thread safe is the norm for mutable classes, say `StringBuilder`, `ProcessBuilder`, `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, any kind of iterator, `DecimalFormat`, to name some examples of widely used mutable classes which are not thread safe and not enforcing a single threaded use.

Note that you could simply add a `synchronized` to the consumer’s `accept` method to enforce the execution of a single thread at a time. When being used in a sequential context, there is a chance the JVM’s optimizer eliminates the associated overhead.

But the simplest solution is to document the requirements and be done with it. If someone uses your class incorrectly, they will get the problems they asked for. You can perform validity checks on a best-effort basis, but trying to make a software bullet-proof wastes a lot of efforts for no benefit.

Comment: If we are using a lambda expression, is using a synchronized block on a static Object equivalent?

Comment: Almost. The `synchronized` `accept` method only locks on the instance. Locking on a static object is like locking on the class.

Comment: If that static object is declared within the lambda, it should not block any threads accessing methods in the rest of the class. Am I right?

Comment: i was afraid so, i dont really see it as the responsibility of the consumer, but though maybe the streams api supported somehow signaling intent to the stream (with complile level annotations for example)  like @NotThreadSafe

Comment: @user7 you can’t declare a static object within a lambda. Within a lambda expression, you can only create local objects and synchronizing on local objects has no effect. You have to declare and initialize a variable outside the lambda expression to synchronize on it. But it might be within the same scope as the lambda expression.

Comment: Ya. My bad (I mistyped it). I meant kind of the same. Thanks. But I don't get what you mean by `Locking on a static object is like locking on the class`. They are not the same *if* there are multiple `NonThreadsafeConsumer` instances.

Comment: @user7 I was referring to the outer class. If all consumers lock on the same object, stored in a `static` field of the outer class, it has an effect similar to locking on the outer class. In contrast, if all consumers have a `synchronized` `accept` method, they’re only locking on their particular instance.

Comment: just a side note on the 'add synchronized', adding locking in the streams API can cause deadlocks see for example https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue223.html

Comment: @pvgoddijn this can only happen when already holding the lock before entering the stream operation. When using a local lock (like a privately held object of the consumer), this can’t happen. That’s exactly the reason why the scope of lock variables should be limited.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a factory pattern which forces the user to get the Consumer from a factory instead of instantiating it directly.

The factory could take a Boolean parameter which indicates whether the stream is parallel or not.

This isn't the nicest work around but it may help the implementer of `doIt()` not miss out on making the Stream sequential.

Hope this helps or at least gives you some ideas of how to go about implementing this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "b");

    strings.stream()
            .forEach(ConsumerFactory.getConsumer(false));
}

static class ConsumerFactory {
    static Consumer getConsumer(boolean isPar) {
        if (isPar) {
            //Handle Parallel
        }

        return new NonThreadsafeConsumer<>();
    }
}

static class NonThreadsafeConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
        //Do non-threadsafe stuff here
    }
}
```